# How to modify an existing part in an installed integrated library in Altium designer?

Tags: altium

I'm new to PCB design, I'm using Altium to design a PCB. I have installed a few useful libraries. Sometimes in my design I find that a part is not exactly what I want, it needs some modifications. Is it possible to make changes to the library and then immediately use it? When I open the integrated library It asks me to extract it, then I compile it and reinstall the library! I'm sure I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: A sugggestion: if you modify an existing part, or make a new part, save it in your own library, not in one of Altiium's - this way you won't lose your modifications when Altium replaces the libraries during an upgrade.

Comment: You can click Design -> Make PCB Library from the PCB view.  This will make a local library (.PcbLib) that is a "snapshot" of all the parts used in that library at the time of creation and you can modify any of them to suit your needs.  You're essentially forking it.